# Aligning a tree based list correctly with css/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the data presenting itself fine in the sense that the children are indented to some extent, however for the case where I have a connector the aligning is off. I'm trying to achieve something that looks like this

```
Item1
 Child1
  Child1-2
 Child2
  Child2-2
Item2
```

Where all items / divs align well on the right. I tried to use float: right and build off that, but the divs lose hieght. The connecters i rendered calculate its height based off the parent/ previous divs so im not sure what to do.

Problem: Trying to align divs correctly and in a meaningful way.
E.G.
Im trying to align child elements to the right, the alignment in my jsfiddle is wrong at the 2nd level chil, and i don't exactly know the best way to go about and fix it

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qatuvha5/28/

Colors were to differentiate between the levels of which a child lives

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Im trying to align child elements to the right, the alignment in my jsfiddle is wrong in the 2nd level children, and i don't exactly know the best way to go about and fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try adding padding to the child wrap container:

```
.categorylevel.level-2 {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

### [Updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/qatuvha5/31/)